# How can I fix this error? TypeError: compute_minimal_traces() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event_log'

Tags: python, design-patterns, instance, traceswitch

This is the code: I need help on solving those errors.

I tried to create an instance. I get the following errors. The main goal is to find an pattern from that event_log. Please let me know what other details I need to fix on this.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Define the phoenixscript class
class phoenixscript:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def parse_event_log(event_log):
        # Extract the unique events from the event log
        events = set()
        for trace in event_log:
            # Make sure that trace is a collection of events
            if not isinstance(trace, (list, tuple)):
                continue

            # Iterate over the events in the trace
            for event in trace:
                # Add each element in the event to the set of unique events
                events.update(event)

        # Return the unique events
        return list(events)

    # Define the find_pattern method
    def find_pattern(self, event_log):
        # Parse the event log to extract the relevant information
        events = self.parse_event_log(event_log)

        # Convert the list of strings into a 2-dimensional array
        events_array = [[event] for event in events]

        # Use the K-means clustering algorithm to identify patterns in the data
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
        kmeans.fit(events_array)
        patterns = kmeans.cluster_centers_

        # Return the identified patterns
        return patterns

    # Define the compute_minimal_traces method
    def compute_minimal_traces(self, event_log):
        # Read the event log from the given traces
        events_list = pd.DataFrame(event_log)

        # Use the find_pattern function to identify the minimal number of traces needed
        patterns = self.find_pattern(event_log)
        num_traces = len(patterns)

        # Print the number of minimal traces
        print(num_traces)

        # Return the number of minimal traces
        return num_traces

    # Define the event log
event_log = ([
        ["status-Open", "Workflow", "summary", "summary", "assignee", "Attachment", "Attachment",
         "status-Patch Available",
         "Attachment", "Attachment", "Attachment", "Attachment", "summary", "Fix Version", "resolution",
         "status-Resolved",
         "status-Closed"],
        ["status-Open", "Workflow", "summary", "issuetype", "summary"],
        ["status-Open", "Workflow", "summary", "description", "Fix Version", "labels", "Fix Version", "resolution",
         "status-Resolved"],
        ["status-Open", "Workflow"]])

    # Create an instance of the phoenixscript class
phoenix = phoenixscript()
num_traces = phoenix.compute_minimal_traces(event_log)

    # Print the results
print("The minimal number of traces needed is:", num_traces)
```

I tried to create an instance. I get the following errors.

```
Create an instance of the phoenixscript class
phoenix = phoenixscript()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/randeepsingh/Desktop/pythonProjectRDA/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    class phoenixscript:
  File "/Users/randeepsingh/Desktop/pythonProjectRDA/main.py", line 75, in phoenixscript
    num_traces = compute_minimal_traces(event_log)
TypeError: compute_minimal_traces() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event_log'
```

Ignore the following statements(The code doesntworks fine and I get thfv dfe correct result.But if I have a huge list of wofsdbsfgbrds say 150sgdbsgb0, it's not feasible to type and creagsfbsfgbte a dictionary that long.So I made a function which takegsbs thogfbvse words from the list, implements the techsdgbsgdbnisdbfgbque I dicussed above and creates the graph for me which works just ffgdsdfinesbg until here.But wsfgbfghen I try to get the shsfgbsortest distance besgfbsfgbtween two words, I get the following error)

Comment: The code has `num_traces = phoenix.compute_minimal_traces(event_log)`, but the error message has `num_traces = compute_minimal_traces(event_log)`.  These do not match.  Please post your real code.

Comment: It's probably a bug with the versions.